# Is there any way to increase the size of binary file without changing it's properties?

Tags: c#, binary, size, executable

I'm looking for a way to increase the size of binary file, for example by adding some extra bits at the end of the file, but I want to keep it's original purpose.

To be specific, I have an executable file. I want to add something to it to increase it's size, but I also want to keep it working the way it was before modification.

I think this trick may work with ZIP files, but I'm not sure about any others.

Comment: Aren't most files binary? What is this "binary file"? An exe? A .net exe? Do you have access to the source/compilation or are you looking to retrofit?

Comment: You can append data to an unsigned executable, and it should still work. If it's signed, you'd have to re-sign it after appending the data.

Comment: Yeah, it would be an exe. And I want to do it without changing the source of that exe.

Comment: So I can just append any data at the end of unsigned file and it will still work?

Comment: What are the *data* (extra bits) you are talking about? I recall there was `PE packer` (type this in google), to shrink exe-files. I could be wrong, they are also allow to carry extra data (like if you compress into a single executable whole directory).